# Angular 2 model is not getting emitted to component view in OnPush component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components

I don't know why but my component sometimes doesn't emit the model to the component's view until I click somewhere on the page. The component is using `OnPush` for its `ChangeDetectionStrategy` and I'm trying to emit, propagate change and mark the path for change detection but nothing seems to work.

**EDIT:** I'm also using `ControlValueAccessor` to make it work with forms, which I'm not sure if it's been done correctly here.

I guess there's something wrong with the `@Output()` of the `ngModel/model`, but I haven't been able to solve it despite trying different solutions such as:

```
@Output('ngModelChange') modelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(true);
@Output('ngModelChange') modelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
@Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

What I find strange is that this is not happening on all views.. But I haven't found anything that's different about the views, and the model is getting set correctly in the `ngOnInit`, but the view is not updated all of the times.

Component:

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
    {
     provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
     useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectComponent),
     multi: true
   }
  ]
})

export class SelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy, OnInit  {
  @Input('ngModel') model: any;
  @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(true);

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}

  writeValue(value: any) {

    if (value !== undefined) {
      this.model = value;
    }
  }

  ...

  ngOnInit() {

    // Set some default values
    this.isRequired = this.isRequired || false;
    this.isDisabled = this.isDisabled || false;
    this.placeholder = this.placeholder || '';
    this.options = this.options || [];
    this.optionsLabel = this.optionsLabel || 'name';
    this.uniqueKey = this.uniqueKey || 'id';

    if (!this.model && this.isRequired) {
      this.model = this.options[0];
    }
    else if (!this.isRequired) {
      this.model = null;
    }

    console.log(this.model);
    this.propagateChange(this.model);
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this.model);
  }

  ...
}
```

View:

```
...
<div>{{model ? model[optionsLabel] : placeholder}}</div>
...
```

Using it like this:

```
<custom-select [(ngModel)]="item.optionType" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [options]="settingTypes" [isRequired]="true"></custom-select>
```

Comment: Any reason why you name your input/output `ngModel` and `ngModelChange`? That's likely to conflict with the `ngModel` directive used in forms.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm using `ControlValueAccessor`, and I need to do checks on the `model` that's why I'm doing `@Input('ngModel') model`, seems to work in all cases except this odd one.